# Fade in/Fade out, Fixed/Sticky Header

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout, fadeto

Okay, I know it seems like I've asked this question already, for which @adeneo had previously answered and apreciated, however I am rattling my brains because I just can't get this to work.

I'm trying to make my 'fixed' positioned header 'fadeTo' 0.5 Opacity when scrolled down and fade back to full opaqueness ('opacity': 1.0) when the user scrolls back to the top?

Here's what I have:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
$("#header").fadeTo(400, 1);
}else{
$("#header").fadeTo(400, 0.5);

}
});
```

At the moment, using this code only seems to make it 'fadeTo' 0.5 opacity when scrolled down but it then won't fade back to full opaqueness (opacity: 1.0) when scrolled back to the top.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems is that you're executing an animation of 400ms for **every** time your user scrolls the page, this generates a very long queue of effects which have no visible effect, e.g. animating to `1` opacity for each time the `scroll` event fires with `scrollTop > 50`, adding a very long queue of invisible effects until the fading out effect takes place.

A simple way to remedy that is using [`.stop(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before executing the `fadeTo`, this way the element effects queue will be always cleared before executing the given animation.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $("#header").stop(true).fadeTo(400, 0.5);
    } else {
        $("#header").stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VAMUk/)

But even so you will still be executing animations unnecessarily, so I'd recommend using [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the faded state and only animate when necessary:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var header = $("#header");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        if (!header.data('faded')) header.data('faded', 1).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 0.5);
    } else if (header.data('faded')) {
        header.data('faded', 0).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5nwJ/1/)

ps. I've inverted your opacity values as your question's code's logic didn't correspond to your desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for responding dude. I've tried implementing both of these and neither work?

Comment: Make sure you've included the jQuery library above this script and wrap my answer code inside a DOM ready handler: `$(function() { /*paste code from answer here*/ });`.

Comment: @JamieSmith Oh I just noticed there were some hidden unicode chars at the end of the code when I copied it from jsfiddle. Try copying the code from my answer again (erase the old one completely or it will generate a syntax error).

Comment: I have placed this inside a DOM ready function i.e $(document).ready(function() { }); and I know there are no syntax erros as I'm using Dreamweaver anyway, which'll tell me if there's something wrong - still doesn't work, infact it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Actually scrap what I just said above. Seems to be working perfectly now. Thank you so much - you're a ledge... wait for it...  end!